# Button Click Event Not Working ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleWinner = this.handleWinner.bind(this);
    }

    handleWinner(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Buttet Pressed")
    }

   render() {
       return (
           <td key=1><button onClick={this.handleWinner}>Click Me</button></td>
       )
}
```

My function is Not Dispatching on Button Click

Comment: Tried the same code in a [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7L6l1mRy). Seems to be working. Please check for if you are missing something.

Comment: can't have `key=1` - should be `key={1}` or `key="1"` - or the jsx parser will throw. but yes, it works - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxRavE

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` function is missing a `}`.

```
render() {
  return(
    <td key=1><button onClick={this.handleWinner}>Click Me</button></td>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the brackets properly

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleWinner = this.handleWinner.bind(this);
    }

    handleWinner(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Buttet Pressed")
    }

    render() {
      return <div key=1>
        <button onClick={this.handleWinner}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'))
```